# Link a SharePoint 2013 table list to a task

Tags: connection, list, sharepoint-2013

I currently link an MS Access table to SharePoint 2013 table (list) called tbl_WL_JobID and it currently feeding live data between each other.  Now I'm trying to link certain columns from the SharePoint table (tbl_WL_JobID) to a SharePoint task (web part).

I created a new SharePoint Task page called CS_Task and then I inserted the SharePoint table called tbl_WL_JobID as a web part on the same page.  I then tried to create a connections to send row of data from tbl_WL_JobID to CS_Task, but I didn't get the results I wanted.

The problem I have is that I want all of the tbl_WL_JobID to appear in the CS_Task, but with only certain columns or information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
JP